# config change not reflected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few hyperlinks whose values are assigned in the code behind.
This assignment happens in the Page_Init event.

But the values are picked up from the web.config.

I changed the values in the web.config but this is not being reflected in the hyperlink.

I have done app pool recycle, iis reset and cleared temporary asp.net files.

Need suggestions to resolve this.

Edit: Posting code as requested:

`this.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Footer.Link1.Url"];`

This is done in a method SilentLogin_PreRender which in turn is called in OnInit event

`this.PreRender += new System.EventHandler(this.SilentLogin_PreRender);`

Comment: have you debugged your code? are you doing post(backs) (viewstate could be a problem here...)?

Comment: check your key for appsetting value in codebehind and we.config file. They should match excatly

Comment: check if you are updating the right web config file and it's required key.

Comment: I have debugged my code and during debugging it works fine. I can't build and deploy on that server. (But that is why the web.config is for... so that I don't need to build again)

Comment: @getbacktosrinu In web.config file only for setting in application level and if u made any changes all session are reset. if you made change on web.config iis automatically restart ur app.

Comment: @AnantDabhi I am aware of that. But that didn't work out so I IISreset.